# import Vue from 'vue' has report an error

Tags: vue.js

I have a new Vue project by vue-cli3. When I used these commands, I got an `undefined` type error. Here's code

```
import Vue from 'vue'
```

The error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'use' of undefined
```

When running `console.log(Vue)` in the browser shows "undefined" ,and I'm sure that I have installed Vue. Using absolute path to find Vue, but I don't see my `node_moudles` accessible folder in the code.

Comment: The log words  ' Vue'  was part from 'import Vue from "vue" '

Comment: please share relevant code..whichever part you made changes

Comment: what vue version are you using?

Comment: @vue/cli 4.5.7 this version

Answer (score 0):

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'


const Home = () => import('../views/home/home')
const Cart = () => import('../views/cart/Cart')
const Category = () => import('../views/category/Category')
const Profile = () => import('../views/profile/Profile')

console.log(Vue);

Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

Bowser report methods of use is undefined